# How to get the max values of a line?

Tags: r, dataframe

Please, I would like to get the max values of each line and put it in the final column

This is the data frame:

```
dput(ejemplo)

structure(list(Trat = c("GFF1 (F1 - Fertilizante Químico (FQ) 100%)Granadilla", 
"GFF1 (F1 - Fertilizante Químico (FQ) 100%)Granadilla", "GFF2 (50% quimico y 50%organico)"
), Fuente = c("Abotek", "Equilibrio Ca", "Abotek"), `Nitrogeno (N)` = c(104.733333333333, 
0, 120.2), `Fosforo (PsO5)` = c(4.18933333333333, 0, 4.808), 
    `Potasio (K2O)` = c(24.0886666666667, 0, 27.646), `Boro (B)` = c(0.104733333333333, 
    0, 0.1202), `Calcio (CaO)` = c(NA, 39.05, 0), `Magnesio (MgO)` = c(5.23666666666667, 
    3.5145, 6.01), `Zinc(ZnO)` = c(0.104733333333333, 0, 0.1202
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is that I like

```
dput(ejemplo_with_MaxValeu)

structure(list(Trat = c("GFF1 (F1 - Fertilizante Químico (FQ) 100%)Granadilla", 
"GFF1 (F1 - Fertilizante Químico (FQ) 100%)Granadilla", "GFF2 (50% quimico y 50%organico)"
), Fuente = c("Abotek", "Equilibrio Ca", "Abotek"), `Nitrogeno (N)` = c(104.733333333333, 
0, 120.2), `Fosforo (PsO5)` = c(4.18933333333333, 0, 4.808), 
    `Potasio (K2O)` = c(24.0886666666667, 0, 27.646), `Boro (B)` = c(0.104733333333333, 
    0, 0.1202), `Calcio (CaO)` = c(NA, 39.05, 0), `Magnesio (MgO)` = c(5.23666666666667, 
    3.5145, 6.01), `Zinc(ZnO)` = c(0.104733333333333, 0, 0.1202
    ), Requerimiento = c(104.733333, 39.05, 120.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `pmax`

```
library(dplyr)
 ejemplo <- ejemplo %>%
    mutate(Requerimento  = do.call(pmax, c(across(where(is.numeric)), 
     na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
> as.data.frame(ejemplo)
                                                  Trat        Fuente Nitrogeno (N) Fosforo (PsO5) Potasio (K2O)  Boro (B)
1 GFF1 (F1 - Fertilizante Químico (FQ) 100%)Granadilla        Abotek      104.7333       4.189333      24.08867 0.1047333
2 GFF1 (F1 - Fertilizante Químico (FQ) 100%)Granadilla Equilibrio Ca        0.0000       0.000000       0.00000 0.0000000
3                     GFF2 (50% quimico y 50%organico)        Abotek      120.2000       4.808000      27.64600 0.1202000
  Calcio (CaO) Magnesio (MgO) Zinc(ZnO) Requerimento
1           NA       5.236667 0.1047333     104.7333
2        39.05       3.514500 0.0000000      39.0500
3         0.00       6.010000 0.1202000     120.2000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the conditional ifelse statement:

```
df$Requerimiento <- ifelse(df$Fuente == "Equilibrio Ca", df$`Calcio (CaO)`, df$`Nitrogeno (N)`)
```

output

[image]